# ASP.NET Master Page Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2003-r2

I have this directory structure:

```
[website]
  [folder]
    Default.aspx
  Default.aspx
  Web.config
```

The **Page Directive** in the file in `[folder]` was created by Visual Studio 2010 when I added a new **Web Form using Master Page**:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="website.folder.Default" %>
```

When I run this application in the debugger (using localhost), it works fine.

When I push it up to the server (Windows Server 2003 R2), that same page produces a **Parser Error** on the **Page Directive** line:

> **Parser Error**
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** The file '/website/folder/Page.Master' does not exist.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="website.folder.Default" %>
>   Line 2:
>
> **Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1008

### What needs to be configured on the server to eliminate this error message?

Comment: It looks like your server is treating `/folder` as the root folder.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Yes, I agree. I do not know how to stop that behavior, though.

Comment: Can you actually navigate to that root `default.aspx` or was the site just configured incorrectly in IIS? (going to `thesite.com/default.aspx` is the page in `folder`)

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Yes, I can navigate to the root. Each of the different folders within root is going to be a separate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On our server, I used IIS Manager to delete all of the files in the [website] folder, then republished it through Visual Studio 2010.

It seems to be working now.

Clearly, I don't know enough about how the whole IIS system works!